# Where is the center of power of Gilead?

Tags: the-handmaids-tale

In the season 5, episode 8 of The Handmaid's tale "Motherland" commander Lawerence is referred to as

> The architect of Gilead

As well as his plan for "New Bethlehem" which is a major policy change seems to put him as one of the most important and powerful people in all of Gilead. On the other hand, he seems to still be in Boston from his very first appearance up to the current episodes.

However, Washington DC was still referred to as the Capitol of Gilead and was shown in Season 3 as the center of power.

So how come Lawrence with all his influence and importance isn't located in Washington DC, and that Putnum, who is also a commander located in Boston and not DC (and such seems as only of minor influence on the "federal" Gilead level) has the power to

> try and interfere with the New Bethlehem plan.

Comment: Good question.  The power structure of Gilead is somewhat hard to determine.  I don't think it's that far-fetched for some "intellectual architect" type to be outside the capital, especially as he was devoted to his sick wife. He may simply have refused to relocate, and not been interested in further climbing the political ranks.  The same cannot be said of Putnum though